# Python for loops stops for no reason after near million iterations

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, prime-factoring

I have been trying to solve Project Euler, but I'm stuck on the [third problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=3). I am using python to find the largest prime factor number for the given number. I tried for-loop and then while-loop. Both of the loops works for small digits, but not to bigger digits. The loops stops when it reaches to near million iterations.

There could be another way to solve the problem, but my question is, why does the loop stops abruptly?

**To find the largest prime factor number for the given number**

*using for loop*

```
prime_lst = []
prime_fac = 0
number = 600851475143
for i in range(2,int(number/2)):
    if number%i == 0:
        for j in range(2,i):
            if i%j == 0:
                prime_fac += 1
        if prime_fac < 1:
            print(i)
            prime_lst.append(i)
print(prime_lst[len(prime_lst)-1])
```

*using while loop*

```
def prim_fac(n):
    i = 2
    prime_fac = []
    prime_num = 0
    while i < n:
        if n % i == 0:
            j = 2
            while j < i:
                if i % j == 0:
                    prime_num += 1
                j += 1
            if prime_num < 1:
                prime_fac.append(i)
        i += 1
    print(prime_fac[len(prime_fac)-1])

pri_fac(600851475143)
```

Comment: What do you observe that makes you think that the loops stops "aburptly"?

Comment: What error is printed?

Comment: I tried the first code and it is taking forever to run, but it is keeping on going

Comment: Where are you running it? Perhaps it is in some sort of timed-out container?

Comment: @norok2 I added a print statement to print _i_ after the first loop. It was running seamlessly until it reaches around 700k or 800k mark. After that it's not moving further nor quits. I used jupyter in Windows 10.

Comment: @Błotosmętek There was no error. The process is running without any output.

Comment: @JeanZibbin You have probably reached the limit of Jupyter buffer. The process will run for a while I suspect, you'd just see no output in Jupyter. If you run this from the console you should see this keep on printing (mine is...)

Comment: @norok2 Thank you for the info. I tried several editor based terminal, all had the same issue. But I tried now to run it from powershell directly. And it runs.